# "version" key not founded in connect django and elastic-apm

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch-5, elastic-apm

i want to connect my django project with elastic apm
but when i run my project, i see this line :

```
No version key found in server response
```

but my elastic server response have this key :

```
{
  "name" : "something",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ikPV-LjKQ2mxKz3Nr0pNTQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.16.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "2b937c44140b6559905130a8650c64dbd0879cfb",
    "build_date" : "2021-12-18T19:42:46.604893745Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and this is my django settitngs :

```
ELASTIC_APM = {
   'SERVICE_NAME': 'apm-inolinx',
   'DEBUG': env('DEBUG'),
   'SERVER_URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200',
}
```

Comment: As you pointed out in your own answer, "version" to which the log message was referring was the version of the APM Server. `server_url` must be an instance of the APM Server.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install [apm server](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/installing.html)

First, we should install apm stack and then install our apm integration with Django